# Conditionally load a UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to conditionally load a UserControl according to a property. If the property is "true" then we load the UserControl in XAML. Let's say the property is named: `IsCameraSupported`. Set the `Visibility` to `Collapsed` should **NOT** be the right solution, since I totally do not want to include it in the XAML file.

Can someone give me a code example to do this, in XAML only?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
I misunderstood the question at first glance. This is the updated response.

You can use Frame control. In the Frame control, you can navigate to Page having camera control.

How to call view method from View model

1. Fire an event from IsCameraSupported setter in View Model.
2. Subscribe View to View Model event
3. Call Frame.Navigate in the event handler in view code behind.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

You can create BooleanToVisibilityConverter, and use DataBinding.

http://www.rhyous.com/2011/02/22/binding-visibility-to-a-bool-value-in-wpf/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx

Converter code

```
public class BooleanVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region Constructors

    public BooleanVisibilityConverter()
        : this(true)
    { }

    public BooleanVisibilityConverter(bool collapseWhenInvisible)
        : base()
    {
        CollapseWhenInvisible = collapseWhenInvisible;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public bool CollapseWhenInvisible { get; set; }

    public Visibility FalseVisibility
    {
        get
        {
            if (CollapseWhenInvisible)
                return Visibility.Collapsed;
            else
                return Visibility.Hidden;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return Visibility.Visible;
        if ((bool)value)
            return Visibility.Visible;
        else
            return FalseVisibility;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return true;
        return ((Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Set the visibility is NOT the solution as it will still load the UserControl and execute some initialization process.

Answer (score -1):

Use a Trigger or an Converter class that sets the visibility to collapsed when yr bool is true

during runtime yo can do this

```
if(IsCameraSupported)
{
    var myControl = new MyControl();
    MyCanvas.Children.Add(myControl);
    Canvas.SetLeft(myControl, 20);
    Canvas.SetTop(myControl, 20);

}
```

Comment: It seems like u have not get my meaning. I dont want to include UserControl if the property is false. Set the visibility to collapsed will still load the UserControl, but not visible and do not occupy space.

Comment: And you absolutly dont want to set it up using code behind/ during runtime

Answer (score -1):

I would use a `ContentControl` and in a `DataTrigger` set the `ContentTemplate` to your `UserControl` if `IsCameraSupported` is `True`

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyUserControlTemplate">
    <local:MyUserControl />
</DataTemplate>

<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Property="{Binding IsCameraSupported}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource MyUserControlTemplate}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>  
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```